# DriverManager.getConnection cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am trying to connect a Java program to a database in localhost. My problem seems to be very simple, but I cannot find any answer.

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

> DriverManager.getConnection cannot be resolved to a type

On the following code:

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("Error found " + ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

// Here is where the error pops up
Connection connection = new DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/project3", "root", "root");
```

I am assuming I screwed up some installation, but I am not completely sure what.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no need for ''new" opereator for DriverManager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why `new` here?

Just use

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/project3", 
                                                            "root", "root");
```

`getConnection()` is `static` method. just call it as above.

Answer (score 1):

Just Edit your code like this

```
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
System.out.println("Error found " + ex);
ex.printStackTrace();
}


Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project3", "root", "root");
```

Avoid new And put **:** after jdbc:mysql